# Очистка кэша всех программ

Tags: android, кэширование

Использую вот такой вот код:

```
   try
                {
                  Class[] classMethods = new Class[2];
                  classMethods[0] = Long.TYPE;
                  classMethods[1] = IPackageDataObserver.class;
                  Method localMethod = pm.getClass().getMethod("freeStorageAndNotify", classMethods);
                  Object[] classParams = new Object[2];
                  classParams[0] = Long.valueOf(getEnvironmentSize() - 1L);
                  classParams[1] = new IPackageDataObserver.Stub()
                  {
                    public void onRemoveCompleted(String paramAnonymousString, boolean paramAnonymousBoolean)
                      throws RemoteException
                    {

                    }
                  };
                  localMethod.invoke(pm, classParams);
                }
                catch (Exception localException)
                {
                  while (true)
                    localException.printStackTrace();
                }
```

IPackageDataObserver.aidl и   
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />` в наличии

Идеи почему не работает?
Кстати проверял аналогичные приложения там все отличное работает с этим методом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, примерно так

```
Method[] methods = pm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method m : methods)
    {
        if(m.getName().equals("freeStorageAndNotify"))
        {
            try
            {
                m.invoke(pm, Long.MAX_VALUE, null);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

В качестве параметра для размера очищаемого кеша надо передавать Long.MAX_VALUE т.е максимално возможное значение

Answer (score 0):

1. Посмотри на этот [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37279) - причина походу в этом.
2. А метод `freeStorageAndNotify` - есть в наличии, проверял? Его может не быть для некоторых API.

Comment: 1. Дело похоже не в этом.
2. Да метод существует. Эксепшен не выпадает.

Я даже больше скажу, я его достал при декомпиле из аналогичной прилы, там на том же девайсе все отлично работает.

Comment: Может надо пермишен на `DELETE_CACHE_FILES`?

Comment: Добавил. Ничего не изменилось